# Auto-increment number according to cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can i automatically increment a number (product ref.) according to the value of a cell?
I have this sample table:

[image]

I need to see the value on the Description column and give a Product Ref for each product.

How can i do this?

Thank you in advance

Regards

Comment: Can you please elaborate with example as we some confusion in your question?
You have mention you need automatically increment in product ref. col according to value in description and also write that you need to see the value on the Description col as well

Comment: Do you need to use google-apps-script? Should be able to generate product ref with a formula.

Comment: At this point i only have the Description column filled with the fruit. The Product Ref column is empty. 
I think that i need a script that will fill automatically in the Product Ref. but i'm not sure.

Here is a sample

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OeP8MUcmQehKO7iMtgQihTiNjQHp32Y7Kb_nBC1W93o/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in cell `A1`:

```
=arrayformula({"Product Ref:";if(B2:B<>"",vlookup(B2:B,{unique(B2:B),if(unique(B2:B)<>"","R"&text(row(A2:A)-1,"0000"),)},2,0),)})
```

[image]